# Прокси в браузере

Tags: webbrowser, http, proxy

Ребят, появился вопрос, не по программированию, правда. Может, кто знает и поможет мне.

**Задача:** Присвоить каждой вкладе в браузере проксю или же открыть N браузеров, независимых друг от друга (чтобы можно было в них указать проксю).

**Как пробовал:**

1. Через portable-версию мозиллы - не получается, при открытии второй копии portable-версии мозилла выдает ошибку (что копия уже запущена).
2. Попробовал запустить эту portable версию через SandBoxie - результат одинаковый.
3. Пробовал через браузер k-meleon, к сожалению, там присваивается прокся ко всему браузеру, а не ко вкладкам.
4. Пробовал различные профили в браузерах - тоже не дало результата.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, такая фишка была у браузера Maxthon.

Comment: Есть еще FoxyProxy для ОгненногоЛиса как плагин - посмотрите, может, умеет работать со вкладками

Comment: Если поможет, то попробуй сделать так http://habrahabr.ru/post/111079/

Comment: @codarapeh, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1:
В Firefox создаём профили (запуск менеджера профилей с ключем `firefox.exe -p`). Затем после создания профилей создаём ярлыки на запуск с каждым профилем: `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -p prof1 -no-remote`.

**ВАЖНО использовать ключ *-no-remote***, он позволяет запускать множество копий Огнелиса. Устанавливаем на каждый профиль дополнение "FoxyProxy" (как-то так называлось) - и вуаля! Еще можно "CookieManager", если хотите тыщу вконтактов открыть. :)

Вариант 2:
Можно запускать приватные окна, в них будут доступны дополнения профиля, из которого были окна запущены, но сами по себе они будут независимы. Минус - после закрытия все данные пропадают (заполненные формы, история адресов).